# Heroku and Environments -domains are not working

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am finding that managing production and staging env's on heroku truly a painful process esp with domains, git etc.

1) I created app called htest.

2) In the htest directory I did the below:

```
heroku create --app htest-staging --remote staging
heroku create --app htest-production --remote production

heroku domains:add staging.mydomain.com --app htest-staging --remote staging
heroku domains:add production.mydomain.com --app htest-production --remote production
```

3) I committed the app and started service

```
git push staging master
heroku ps --app htest-staging --remote staging
```

3) I add domain to route53 with the cname of htest-staging.herokuapp.com

```
heroku info --app htest-staging
=== htest-staging
Web URL:       http://htest-staging.herokuapp.com/
```

as expected I get web page not found.

What is even more troubling is that when I go to http://htest-staging.herokuapp.com/ I get this on the page:

```
Heroku | Welcome to your new app!
Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.
```

My python app should have said hello world.

So..how do I resolve?

Comment: Did the deploy go successful? Check the app in your dashboard and make sure it is working.

Comment: what does `heroku domains -r production` give you? I'm also pretty sure you don't need to pass --app and --remote, you might be confusing things passing both.